# Segment Tree Approach in solving

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have given an Array having N element and **Having Three Type of Queries**

**Query 1:**
Add a value C to all the element in Range [L,R] i.e `A[i]+=c where L<=i<=R`

**Query 2** Assign a Value C to all the element in Range [L,R] i.e `A[i] =c where L<=i<=R`
**Query 3** Getting the Sum of all the element from L to R

 I have solve it **Using Segment Tree with Lazy propagation** 
**My Approach:** 
Maintaing an Level[2][n] array where `Level[0][n] store the values to be incremented and Level[1][n] new value that we have to assign`

Here is my change function:

```
public static void change(int curr , int x , int y , int a , int b, long c , long[] T , int add){


           if(level[0][curr]!=-1 || level[1][curr]!=-1){

               if(level[1][curr]!=-1) T[curr] =  (((long)(y-x+1))*level[1][curr])%mod;

               if(level[0][curr]!=-1)
                   T[curr]+= (((long)(y-x+1))*level[0][curr])%mod;
               T[curr]%=mod;

                 if(x!=y){

                     if(level[0][curr]!=-1){

                         if(level[0][2*curr]==-1) level[0][2*curr]= level[0][curr];
                         else level[0][2*curr] += level[0][curr];

                         if(level[0][2*curr+1]==-1) level[0][2*curr+1]= level[0][curr];
                         else level[0][2*curr+1] += level[0][curr];
                     }



                     if(level[1][curr]!=-1){

                           level[1][2*curr]=level[1][curr];
                           level[1][2*curr+1]=level[1][curr];
                     }

                     level[0][2*curr]%=mod;
                     level[0][2*curr+1]%=mod;

                 }
                 level[0][curr]=level[1][curr]=-1;
           }

           if(x>y || y<a || x>b) return;

           if(a<=x && b>=y){

               if(add==1) T[curr]+= (((long)(y-x+1))*c)%mod;
               else T[curr] = (((long)(y-x+1))*c)%mod;
               T[curr]%=mod;

               if(x!=y){

                   if(add==1)
                   {
                        if(level[0][2*curr]==-1) level[0][2*curr]= c;
                         else level[0][2*curr] +=c;

                         if(level[0][2*curr+1]==-1) level[0][2*curr+1]=c;
                         else level[0][2*curr+1] += c;

                         level[0][2*curr]%=mod;
                         level[0][2*curr+1]%=mod;
                   }else{
                       level[1][2*curr]=c;
                       level[1][2*curr+1]=c;  
                       level[0][2*curr]=-1;
                       level[0][2*curr+1]=-1;
                   }

               }

               return;
           }
           change(2*curr, x, (x+y)/2, a, b, c, T, add);
           change(2*curr+1, (x+y)/2+1, y, a, b, c, T, add);

           T[curr] = T[2*curr]+T[2*curr+1];
           T[curr]%=mod;

    }
```

I am not getting the Correct Answer and could not figure out where i have done wrong i have tried multiple test data and getting the right answer but getting wrong answer with large data set
Please Help me very i have done wrong
[Full Working Code](http://ideone.com/9drONK)

```
 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
    1 ≤ Q ≤ 10^5
    1<=L<=R<=10^5
    1<=Value<=10^9
    Mod = 10^9+7
```

Comment: define `large data set`? I mean the size and the ranges. Also provide some sample input and output

Comment: Make a naive implementation and shoot queries at both until they diverge, then update us with a failing test case.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat i have tried multiple query and getting the right answer but could not figure it out why it is failing on test cases